# Test suite failed to run. Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to test my react component's render, but getting the error below: 
**Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.**
Error doesn't exist if i change the place where follows render my component on document.body , and it exists if this place is some div with some id in body.

Here my component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
{render} from 'react-dom';
import Demo from './demo/demo'
import Demo2 from  './demo2/demo2'
require('./app-styles.sass')

export class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
           <div>
               <Demo2 />
               <Demo />
               <div>Hello jest from react</div>
           </div>
       );
   }
}
render(<App/>, document.getElementById('helloWorldRoot'));
```

Test of this component:

```
import React from 'react'
import {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme'
import {App} from './app'

describe('base component', () => {
  it('renders as a div', () => {
    const application = shallow(<App />);
    expect(application).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

And here is my html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Hello jests' tests</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/app.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="helloWorldRoot"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/app.js"></script>
    </body>
```

What is the problem here?
I will be glad to some advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file you're testing, `app.js`, is attempting to find a DOM element with ID `helloWorldRoot` in the last line. This DOM element does not exist when the element is being rendered by Enzyme - hence the error message.

To fix this, separate the `<App />` component and rendering of it into two files. Make sure the file that mounts the application to the DOM (let's call it `main.js`) does just this one thing and nothing else. The other file, `app.js`, can then be tested using Jest and Enzyme.

So main.js should do no more than:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './app';

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('helloWorldRoot'));
```

And of course the corresponding lines should be removed from `app.js`.

Comment: thx you for your answer but ,i'm sorry, i can't understand how does it work "separate the <App /> component and rendering of it into two files" or even how it should look like. Could you write me a mini-example of your think?

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error while running `jest`.
If you updated jest from major version 21 to 22, this error will pop up, among others. In order to fix, simply deleting `node_modules` won't help. After scouring the docs and issues (and now I don't remember where I saw it in the issues section), I read to:

**delete `yarn.lock` file and try to reinstall**.

This, and only this, worked for me. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how your files could be:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './app';

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('helloWorldRoot'));
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
{render} from 'react-dom';
import Demo from './demo/demo'
import Demo2 from  './demo2/demo2'
require('./app-styles.sass')

export class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
           <div>
               <Demo2 />
               <Demo />
               <div>Hello jest from react</div>
           </div>
       );
   }
}
```

App.test.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme'
import {App} from './app'

describe('base component', () => {
  it('renders as a div', () => {
    const application = shallow(<App />);
    expect(application).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Hello jests' tests</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/app.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="helloWorldRoot"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/app.js"></script>
    </body>
```